# Shell while loop no stopping

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

I'm writing a routine that will identify if a process stops running and will do something once the processes targeted is gone.

I came up with this code (as a test for my future code):

```
#!/bin/bash
value="aaa"
ls | grep $value
while [ $? = 0 ]; 
    do
    sleep 5
    ls | grep $value
    echo $?
done;
echo DONE
```

My problem is that for some reason, the loop never stops and echoes 1 after I delete the file "aaa".

```
0
0    >>> I delete the file at that point (in another terminal)
1
1
1
1
.
.
    .
```

I would expect the output to be "DONE" as soon as I delete the file...

What's the problem?

SOLUTION:

```
#!/bin/bash
value="aaa"
ls | grep $value
while [ $? = 0 ];
    do
    sleep 5
    ls | grep $value
done;
echo DONE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `$?` changes very easily.  In the current version of your code, this line:

```
echo $?
```

prints the status of the previous command (`grep`) -- but then it sets `$?` to 0, the status of the `echo` command.

Save the value of `$?` in another variable, one that won't be clobbered next time you execute a command:

```
#!/bin/bash
value="aaa"
ls | grep $value
status=$?
while [ $status = 0 ]; 
    do
    sleep 5
    ls | grep $value
    status=$?
    echo $status
done;
echo DONE
```

If the `ls | grep aaa` is intended to check whether a file named `aaa` exists, this:

```
while [ ! -f aaa ] ; ...
```

is a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, this was just as an example. My final command is going to be:

ps -ef | grep "mysqldump" | grep -v "grep mysqldump"
while [ $? = 0 ]; 
 do
 sleep 1200
 ps -ef | grep "mysqldump" | grep -v "grep mysqldump";
done;

tar cvzf [dumpdir] [files]
rm [files]

Comment: @Rgonomike: You can write: "while ps -ef | ... | grep mysqldump; do sleep 1200; done".  That will simplify the code.  (Although parsing ps is the wrong way do this.  What you really want is to have the parent of mysqldump do the followon processing, since it is alerted when mysqldump exits.)

Answer (score 2):

`$?` is the return code of the last command, in this case your `sleep`.

Comment: I edited the script as you suggested (just moved my sleep command). It still does not work though... same result.
Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite that loop in much simpler way like this:

```
while [ -f aaa ]; do
   sleep 5;
   echo "sleeping...";
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You ought not duplicate the command to be tested.  You can always write:

```
while cmd; do ...; done
```

instead of

```
cmd
while [ $? = 0 ]; do ...; cmd; done
```

In your case, you mention in a comment that the command you are testing is parsing the output of ps.  Although there are very good arguments that you ought not do that, and that the followon processing should be done by the parent of the command for which you are waiting, we'll ignore that issue at the moment.  You can simply write:

```
while ps -ef | grep -v "grep mysqldump" |
    grep mysqldump > /dev/null; do sleep 1200; done
```

Note that I changed the order of your pipe, since grep -v will return true if it
matches anything.  In this case, I think it is not necessary, but I believe is more
readable.  I've also discarded the output to clean things up a bit.

Comment: There is a trick to avoiding `grep ... | grep -v grep`: `grep '[m]ysqldump'`

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your objective is to wait until a filename containing the string `$value` is present in the local directory and not necessarily a single filename.

try:

```
#!/bin/bash
value="aaa"
while ! ls *$value*; do
  sleep 5
done
echo DONE
```

Your original code failed because `$?`is filled with the return code of the `echo` command upon every iteration following the first.

BTW, if you intend to use `ps` instead of `ls` in the future, you will pick up your own `grep` unless you are clever.  Use `ps -ef | grep [m]ysqlplus`.